# Laravel updateOrCreate ignoring some fields

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I've been pulling my hair for hours now trying to find the problem with this lines of code:

```
    ContentSetting::updateOrCreate(
        ['content_id' => $this->id, 'key' => 'max_width'],
        ['value' => $value]
    );
```

It is supposed to check if there is a row in my content_settings table with a certain content id and the key "max_width" and if so update it and if not create it. It's used in a model mutator, hence the $this.

Anyway, no matter what values I try to put in, this ALWAYS results in this mysql query being executed (only with different time stamps):

```
insert into `content_settings` (`content_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2, '2020-10-15 14:07:00', '2020-10-15 14:07:00')
```

...simply making new rows with empty key and value. Can anyone please spot the error? Or is this a bug somewhere? Something with "key" being a reserved word?

Comment: what about $fillable in your ContentSetting  model? is it contains key and value?

Comment: Doh! I KNEW it would be something totally obvious. Of course! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome, I will add my answer so we can close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should set the fields you want to use in mass assignment in the $[fillable](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment)  array in your model:

```
class ContentSetting extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = ['content_id','key','value'];
}
```

Comment: Just for the record: It would be nice if Laravel signalled this in some way. Would have spared me an hour or two...